# won't boot after upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, 12.10

I forced an upgrade from kubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 and when booting it sticks on the loading screen.  Looking at the boot log shows me that 'Starting K Display Manager' as 'failed'.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of hunting around I wasn't able to find what the issue was, but I found that I could log in if I pressed

```
ctr + alt + F1
```

This gave me hope that my installation wasn't borked.  I found a website that told me to execute this command:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

This did a load of stuff, and at the end told me a few things failed (kubuntu-desktop being one of them), but after a restart my desktop came back.

I hope this helps anyone else having the same issue - if anyone knows *why* this worked, please explain in the comments of this answer.

Comment: Looks like your update process failed in the middle of it (power/network?)

Comment: *"if anyone knows why this worked, please explain in the comments"* - or, better yet - propose an **edit** to the question to improve it.

Comment: @KarthikT I'm pretty sure it didn't power down during the upgrade.